# project symfony 2.8 compatible issue between sonata admin Bundle with other ecommerce bundle(Thelia)

Tags: symfony, e-commerce, sonata-admin

I need some advices.
With my team we work on symfony 2.8 lts on an existent project using sonata admin Bundle.
We need to made e-commerce part but the guys before us use sonata admin bundle.
So the question is : can we use an other e-commerce bundle than the sonata one.
For the moment, we are interested by Thelia Bundle and few little ones, but not sure at this time.

Thx for the future answers and interests.

Answer (score 0):

For what I know Thelia is not a bundle but a complete e-commerce solution build on some Symfony2 components which means the work you already did have to be re-implemented in a new Thelia project.
I do not think this is what you are looking for, it is ?

Since you are already working with SonataAdminBundle, you can take a look to [SonataEcommerceBundle](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/ecommerce/master/doc/index.html) provided by the [Sonata Project](https://sonata-project.org) Team.

Although [Sylius](http://sylius.org/) and [Elcodi](http://elcodi.io/) projects may interest you

Finally here is an [article](https://www.symfony.fi/entry/symfony-and-ecommerce-elcodi-sylius-and-thelia) quickly presenting elcodi, sylius and thelia.

Hope it can help you and your team,

regards

Comment: Thx  for your help ! we have choose Sylius Bundle, is not easy to use with sonata admin but i try ;)